# How to get the module object in the current python file

Tags: python, module

I want to delete the variable in the current module, del is ok, but I want to use delattr, what should I do?

```
a = 10
print(a)
delattr("object?", a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.modules` with `__name__` as the key to get a reference to the current module:

```
import sys
a = 10
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
delattr(this_module, 'a')
```